# Merge two sets of returned json data for loop

Tags: ajax, function

Is it possible to merge two sets of data `data.posts` and `data.comments` so they all come under response in my loop?

```
    success: function(data) {
    datas =  data.posts;
    datas =  data.comments;
    $.each(datas, function(i, response) {
    )}
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course:

```
success: function(data) {
var datas = {};
datas =  data.posts;
datas =  data.comments;
for (var postIndex in data.posts) {
    datas[postIndex] = data.posts[postIndex];
}
for (var commentIndex in data.comments) {
    datas[commentIndex] = data.comments[commentIndex];
}
$.each(datas, function(i, response) {
)}
}
```

But you must know that if `posts` and `comments` have some similar keys, the latter will overwrite the former in the merge result. If you are not ok with that, then please add more information.

Comment: Thank you for that.

Comment: You are welcome.